# How to SET on specific redis server with StackExchange.Redis client?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I have 3 redis servers running in docker containers. From redis-cli I can SET on specific server.

```
SET myValue 100
```

How can I do this with StackExchange.Redis client?

I don't see anything in server api that allows to do that. Bear in mind that I don't know much about Redis at all.

```
var connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost:6379,localhost:6380,localhost:6381");
var server = connection.GetServer("localhost", 6381);
server.???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SE.Redis expects to be managing a single logical keyspace; the support for multiple nodes is intended *either* for master/replica setups, or for redis-cluster (although, in the case of cluster, node discovery is achieved via the redis API, so a single node would be fine if it is reachable). With that in place: the selection of servers is implicit from the operation (i.e. writes need to go to a master, and in the case of "cluster", the keyspace shard mapping should be applied).

If you want to write to separate servers *as though they are separate databases*, you should use a connection per server; not a single connection that spans them all. Right now, SE.Redis is probably detecting 3 master nodes and electing to use one of them arbitrarily. You can see what it thinks by passing a `TextWriter` to the `Connect`/`ConnectAsync` method.